# Prettytable make use of list

Tags: python

I have a 2 lists; one is called teamname and other one scores. I want the values from those lists printed in PrettyTable. I know you can do it by `t.add_row([scores[0]])`, but it only takes the first item from the list (This way I have to know how many items are in a list and have to manually add the amount of rows). You can also do it by doing by entering `t.add_row([scores])`, but then it places the whole list in one line without entering a new row. Is it possible in PrettyTable to just enter the list and get a the data in it in new lines?

I've tried searching for this on the internet, but couldn't find anything.

Example 1:

```
t = PrettyTable(['Teamname', 'Scores'])
    t.add_row([teams, scores])
```

Then you get:

```
+-------------------+--------+
|      Teamname     | Scores |
+-------------------+--------+
| ['test', 'test1'] | [1, 2] |
+-------------------+--------+
```

Example 2:

```
t = PrettyTable(['Teamname', 'Scores'])
t.add_row([teams[0], scores[0]])
t.add_row([teams[1], scores[1]])
```

Then you get:

```
+-------------------+--------+
|      Teamname     | Scores |
+-------------------+--------+
| test              | [1]    |
+-------------------+--------+
| test1             | [2]    |
+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using a for loop and `zip` to iterate through your lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not add the data by columns:

```
t = PrettyTable()
t.add_column('Teamname', teams)
t.add_column('Scores', scores)
```

Comment: That should work. Do you have the latest version of `PrettyTable`?

Comment: Yeah, I found the problem; it should be t = PrettyTable([]) instead of (). Thanks :)